# Alamofire.request().responseJSON no longer available in Alamofire 5

Tags: swift, xcode, url, alamofire

It's my first time using **Alamofire** with **version 5 Beta** but I ran into issues with the Alamofire.request

```
Alamofire.request(yourURL).responseJSON // no longer available.
```

There is no new documentation available and can't work out how to implement it.

The autocomplete for Alamofire now does

```
 Alamofire.Request.init(id: UUID, underlyingQueue: DispatchQueue, serializationQueue: DispatchQueue, eventMonitor: EventMonitor?, interceptor: RequestInterceptor?, delegate: RequestDelegate)
```

I found this function but it doesn't provide the JSON response

```
Alamofire.URLRequest(url: URL)
```

Any ideas how Alamofire.request(yourURL).responseJSON is now implemented?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is now `AF.request` if you want to use the `default` Alamofire `Session` to make requests. Making a request using a custom `Session` is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jon!